# Android name value pairs from an ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

In the following code I am able to retrieve the `_id value` of each record and display it along with the text in a `ListView` but when I select an item from the list the returned value is 0 to N dependent on how the results are laid out in the list.

How can I get the `_id value`, I guess as a named value pair so that when 0 or 1… is selected it outputs the `_id` field and not 0 or 1… for my `OnItemClickListener`

This is my method, it’s messy, once I get it working I’ll try to refine it!

```
private void GetCoordinates(double currentLatitude, double currentLongitude) {

    List<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

    dbBookHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    ourCursor = dbBookHelper.getCoordinates();

    int counta = 0; 
    ourCursor.moveToFirst();                    
    do {                    
        id = ourCursor.getInt(ourCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"));
        BeachName = ourCursor.getString(ourCursor.getColumnIndex("BeachName"));
        beachLatitude = ourCursor.getDouble(ourCursor.getColumnIndex("latitude"));
        beachLongitude = ourCursor.getDouble(ourCursor.getColumnIndex("longitude"));

        distence = ConvertDistance(beachLatitude, beachLongitude);

        if (distence <= 5) {
            ar.add(id + " " + BeachName + " - " + distence + "Kms");
            counta++;               
        }

    } while (ourCursor.moveToNext());

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row2, R.id.beachListText, ar);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "There are " + String.valueOf(counta) + " beaches within a 5km radius!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
}
```

And this is my OnItemClickListener method

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {           
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(id) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Cheers,

Mike.

**Edit:** Thanks guys, I was hoping for a slicker way too!

But I now have a second array holding just the id values with,

```
ar1.add(String.valueOf(id));
```

So the positions are the same, but how do I get them into the OnItemClickListener? I guess somewhere in here???

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row2, R.id.beachListText, ar);
setListAdapter(adapter);

ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
lv.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
```

Comment: Sorry, I was getting confused between adapter types (it's been a long day). The answer from scotinus is basically what I was aiming for. If you use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` for the `ListView` then you can retrieve the `Cursor` inside the `OnItemClickListener`.

Comment: I get what scotinus is saying, I just have no idea how to go about it. I have two arrays with the info I need. My problem is I have no idea what goes on in an OnItemClickListener method. it says it is having "AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id" passed in but I don't know what all that means, where it's coming from or why. anyone???

Comment: "parent" is the adapter associated with the list view, "view" is the list view, "position" is the element of the array that was clicked (the position in the list). In this case "id" is I believe redundant (apparently just gets set to the same value as position). In other implementations of this interface however (such as SimpleCursorAdapter) "id" can be used to provide additional info on the list item (eg. the table rowId).

Comment: I added specific code below showing the array lookup approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is the ArrayAdapter does not know anything about the Cursor or rowId. I think you have 2 choices. The first is to manage the mapping of array position to rowId yourself. For example, create a second array to map the ArrayList position to the rowId, and do a simple lookup in the listener.

If that is not appropriate for some reason then you could create a custom adapter with knowledge of the Cursor, by extending CursorAdapter. It involves over-riding 2 methods newView() and bindView() to allocate and populate the views (with your custom string) that will be displayed in each row. It also provides filtering hooks that would allow you to implement the < 5KM filter you need.

I haven't gone through this particular case myself, but did recently have to extend an ArrayAdapter to implement a SectionIndexer for a very long list. While it was a valuable exercise, I think in your case a custom adapter is possibly overkill. A second array look-up may be simpler and more appropriate.

1) Make your new array a class member so it is accessible in the listener

```
ArrayList<Long> mIdArr = null;
```

2) Create this in a similar way to your String array

```
mIdArr = new ArrayList<Long>();
```

3) Store the rowId at the same point you add to your String array

```
ar.add(id + " " + BeachName + " - " + distence + "Kms");
mIdArr.add(new Long(id));
```

4) Retrieve the Id in your listener like this

```
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {           
        Long rowId = mIdArr.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), String.valueOf(rowId) + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks Scotinus you have gone above and beyond the call of duty but I have tried this a number of ways and I just keep getting a Null Pointer Exception inside the onListClick method. I can’t see how this will can work as mIdArr is still an Array at that stage and ar and mIdArr still have no knowledge of each other.

Comment: It's not a problem trying to help. I'm just learning too and this is good for me also. Where are you hitting the Null exception? I realized my step 3 was wrong - should have allocated the Long object when adding to the array (I've now edited). Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you think ar and mIdArr need to know about each other? The intent is to populate both at the same time, so the corresponding elements are related to each other. That way, you can use "position", which strictly speaking refers to the "ar" array, to look up the corresponding rowId from "mIdArr".

Comment: Thanks Scotinus you are correct. Sorry I was away for a week and had this in the back of my mind the whole time. I tried it once and it didn’t work but it does now. You confused me with 1 and then 2 as I was declaring ArrayList<Long> mIdArr = null; at class level and then declaring ArrayList<Long> mIdArr = new ArrayList<Long>(); again in my method. What I needed to do was just declare the latter at class level and it worked. I love it when that happens. Thanks again Mike.